# Quisque ipse sé díligit, quod quisque per sé sibi cárus est

Tags: translation-check, translation-explanation, spanish, wheelocks-latin

In the 4. sententiae antíquae exercise of the page 86 of Wheelock's Latin steht:

> Quisque ipse sé díligit, quod quisque per sé sibi cárus est.

My attempt to translate to my native Spanish goes

> Cada uno se aprecia a si mismo, que cada uno se cuide por si mismo.

Translating it to English:

> Each one appreciates himself, that each one cares himself.

I am enigmatic about the first *quisque*, the *quod quisque*, and what *per sé*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that there is no subjunctive in the second part, and that [**quod**](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dquod1) has a lot of alternative meanings. One relevant meaning of **quod** that seems to apply here is *because*:

> Everyone loves themselves *because* they hold themselves in esteem for who they are  [lit. everyone are esteemed to themselves for themselves].

A possible translation to Spanish would be:

> Todo hombre se ama a sí mismo, porque [todo hombre] es valioso para sí por sí mimso.

Or, a bit more freely, to make it easier to read:

> Todo hombre se ama a sí mismo, porque encuentra en su propio ser un valor intrínseco.

Comment: Why use both, "per se" = "through themselves" and "sibi" = "for themselves", in the same clause?

Comment: @tony I'm lacking technical terminology, but _per se_ = for who they are, and _sibi carus_ = esteemed to themselves. **Carus** is an adjective, and in you are **carus** (~loved) _to_ someone, since love is subjective.

Comment: @Rafael I think that's right. Aristotle discusses this when he talks about friendship (*philia*). Someone can be "dear to me" because of their utility or pleasure. In that case they would be dear to me, but not *for their own sake*.

Comment: @brianpck and all: I messed up writing that comment. I meant "in _Latin_ you _can be_ carus _to_ someone". I was correcting a previous version and left it unfinished.